# sql-alchemy relationship/ backref - Linking two "users" to one "message" throws error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these two tables. USERS and MESSAGES.

My plan was to have both the sender and receiver of the message (User objects) stored in each message. However I keep getting the below error.

Can someone point me in the right direction to what I'm doing wrong. I guess its the wrong type of join but my brain seems to be malfunctioning.

error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.messages_sent - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

code:

```
class Messages(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_sent = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    date_received = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=True)
    message_text = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    user_id1 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    message_read = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    slogan = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    messages_sent = db.relationship("Messages",backref="message_sender", lazy=True)
    messages_received = db.relationship("Messages",backref="message_receiver", lazy=True)
```

EDIT:

So, reading the docs it looks like I need the foreign_keys param .

I have changed the Messages table to include the sender_id & receiver_id and the User model to include the foreign_keys but I'm now getting this error.

> AttributeError AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute
>   'sender_id'

```
class Messages(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_sent = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    date_received = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=True)
    message_text = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    receiver_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    message_read = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    slogan = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    token_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=True)
    messages_sent = db.relationship("Messages",backref="message_sender", lazy=True, foreign_keys = 'messages.sender_id')
    messages_received = db.relationship("Messages",backref="message_receiver", lazy=True,foreign_keys = 'messages.receiver_id')
```

I've checked the messages table and there is 100% a sender_id in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a .c. is for column

```
 messages_sent = db.relationship("Messages",backref="message_sender", lazy=True, foreign_keys = '[messages.c.sender_id]')
 messages_received = db.relationship("Messages",backref="message_receiver", lazy=True,foreign_keys = '[messages.c.receiver_id]')
```

edited after tested

Comment: No luck - another error  sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Messages->messages, expression 'sender_id' failed to locate a name ("name 'sender_id' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'flaskblog.models.Messages'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Messages.messages_sent - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Comment: I've editied my question with how the code looks now. Thanks

Comment: THANK YOU I did it. I don't understand the .c. can you explain it for me at all in your answer?

Comment: Yes perfectly , i changed it to this.     messages_sent = db.relationship("Messages", backref="message_sender", lazy=True, foreign_keys = '[messages.c.sender_id]')
    messages_received = db.relationship("Messages", backref="message_receiver", lazy=True, foreign_keys = '[messages.c.receiver_id]')

Comment: With the square brackets

Comment: Its working exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks so much I've been avoiding this part as I couldn't get it to work last week.